# Deleting emails in Windows Mail does not delete emails across all mail clients?

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail, email-client, windows-mail

I have setup my gmail account in Windows 10's standard mail app.

I would like to make it so when I delete, read, or otherwise modify an email in the Windows 10 client, for that to show across all my other email reading devices.

For example: When I delete an email on my iPhone, it also is already deleted when I open the mail app on a mac.

Currently, reading an email or marking it as read does not sync. Deleting an email also does not sync.

I would like to be able to delete an email on Windows 10 Mail, and have it be deleted across all mail clients, or read and email or so on.

How do I enable this?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the account to Windows Mail?

Answer (score -1):

I was really struggling as well and then realized (as typically happens) the solution is quite simple! Once you delete or archive a message in Windows mail, hit refresh. This will update the server and voila your message will either be archived or deleleted (depending on your action in Mail) in Gmail. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You likely configured the Mail app using POP (incoming server: `pop.gmail.com`) which simply copies your messages from Gmail.

Instead use IMAP (incoming server : `imap.gmail.com`) where messages are synced in real time.

> [Read Gmail messages on other email clients using IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)
>
> You can read your messages from Gmail in other mail clients, like
>   Microsoft Outlook and Apple Mail, using IMAP. When you use IMAP, you
>   can read your Gmail messages on multiple devices, and **messages are
>   synced in real time.**

Comment: Good thought, but I setup my accounts using the standard Mail method (presents login to Gmail dialog and takes care of the rest). Upon inspection it appears that the account is already setup with IMAP

Comment: I'll leave this answer up as another user with a similar issue may have inadvertently selected POP.